# How To Get Parent Category Slug of Current Post with Multiple Parent Categories

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

I'm trying to improve navigation for my visitors by displaying the parent category on the blog page.

However, for a handful of blog posts, it has more than one parent category.

How do I expand the following code to display all parent categories:

```
$category = get_the_category();
$term_link = get_category_link($category[0]->category_parent);
$parent = get_cat_name($category[0]->category_parent);
if (!empty($parent)) {
echo '<a href="' . $term_link . '">' . $parent . '</a>';
} else {
echo '';
}
```

Comment: Probably iterate over `$category` rather than selecting the first record.